# iOS: Dealing with data and a large amount of views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a general design question for dealing with data. I currently am working on an app that stores about 100+ different unique properties (mostly integers, some strings) and am currently using a single object of a custom class to manage all of them.

I need the data to be "persistent" throughout the app so I currently pass the object via segues. I have managed to build 20+ views, most with their own view controller. I am very new to Objective-C and iOS development and have a feeling this is a bad practice.

I do not understand that much about core data and am not sure if it would be a better solution for me. I have also read about singletons and have heard mixed things about using them for this sort of solution.

In the future, I will need to permanently store the data that is held temporarily in the custom class I have written.

What is the best way to deal with this situation? Is it standard practice to pass the object around over many different views?

Comment: for something like you might look into `SQLite`

Comment: I agree that SQLite would be a good solution when it comes time to store the data on a database. I would really like to know if using segues to push data within the app is the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data needs to permeate through the entire app then a singleton might be a good way to go.

In game dev there is a pattern called the chalkboard pattern that allows any part of the game to read and write to the chalkboard. This can be used for health points, scores, etc...

This would suit you well too. Rather than pushing your data model around all the time just use the singleton to access each bit/ If the data needs to be updated then store the updates to the singleton.

The thing to avoid is using the singleton just because its there. If a bit of data needs to get from one place to another then don't just use the singleton if it isn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you. For me, this made a great deal of sense.

Comment: I have a bit of a follow-up to this to help solidify my understanding. Is it necessary to use the singleton whenever you need to update or add data?